# Fluent Scheduler only run once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, fluent

I'm using `Fluent Scheduler` in my ASP.NET MVC 4 project. I want to create a scheduler that runs at 4am everyday. Here is my code:

**Service**

```
public class ParseService : Registry
{
    public ParseService(string path)
    {
        Schedule(() => ParseHelper.ParseData(path)).ToRunEvery(1).Days().At(4, 0);
    }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

        Application["LogPath"] = Server.MapPath("~/Areas/Admin/LogFiles/");
        TaskManager.Initialize(new ParseService(Application["LogPath"].ToString()));
    }
}
```

The problem is that scheduler only runs once. If I want it to run again at 4am, I have to restart the IIS server. Does anyone know what's wrong with my code? Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the application pool that executed it the first time has been recycled automatically. You need to configure the application pool to stay alive, **if** this is really how you want to do it.

Here is a great tutorial on [how to configure that](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling).

However, I am also in the same breath going to caution you on this. This is better suited as a Windows service or a console application that's launched with Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you. But this library is widely used, so I hope it doesn't have this mistake. Have you ever used it? :(

Comment: @Forte_201092, have what mistake? And no I haven't used it.

Comment: How can a scheduler thread be recycled? If this library lets this happen, it's quite... bad :(

Comment: @Forte_201092: it's not the library, it's IIS. The thread that the scheduler is on is **subject** to the thread pool served to it via the application pool in IIS. There is nothing it could possibly do.

Comment: @Forte_201092 : the purpose of application pool's recycling IS to stop and restart running web sites, independently of running threads. It is a perfectly natural behavior, and to disable app pool recycling is almost never a great solution. Websites are usually not a good way to host background tasks with long intervals between each run.